Unable to use PySide6 on NixOS : qt.qpa.plugin: From 6.5.0, xcb-cursor0 or libxcb-cursor0 is needed to load the Qt xcb platform plugin
I have been unable to use PySide6 on NixOS, I tried to install pyside from nixpkgs, pip and conda but I end up with the same result. I have this example file:
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget

# Only needed for access to command line arguments
import sys

# You need one (and only one) QApplication instance per application.
# Pass in sys.argv to allow command line arguments for your app.
# If you know you won't use command line arguments QApplication([]) works too.
app = QApplication(sys.argv)

# Create a Qt widget, which will be our window.
window = QWidget()
window.show()  # IMPORTANT!!!!! Windows are hidden by default.

# Start the event loop.
app.exec()

Which should open an example window, but I have the following error:
$ python qt.py 
qt.qpa.plugin: From 6.5.0, xcb-cursor0 or libxcb-cursor0 is needed to load the Qt xcb platform plugin.
qt.qpa.plugin: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "" even though it was found.
This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.

Available platform plugins are: vnc, vkkhrdisplay, linuxfb, minimalegl, xcb, eglfs, offscreen, minimal, wayland, wayland-egl.

Aborted (core dumped)

I have tried other solutions online, like installing xcb-util-cursor from nixpkgs, but nothing seemed to help. I am on the unstable branch of nixpkgs. Has anyone been able to make pyside6 work in your nixos setup?

what is the output of: QT_DEBUG_PLUGINS=1 python qt.py

This may not be revelant, but for debian I have to install the following packages:
sudo apt install libxcb-cursor0 libxcb-icccm4 libxcb-keysyms1
I think for NixOS you need to find missing dependencies by:
ldd venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/PySide6/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqxcb.so | grep -i "not found"

references:
"qt.qpa.plugin: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "" even though it was found."

Thank you for the reply, the problem is mostly that the required libraries already exist in the system, but the package is unable to access them in Nix os. I am a beginner to Nix and am still trying to figure out the best way to do this. I just tried a fhs env as well, but that does not work as well.

Install these packages, I have same error when running matplotlib that installed using pip
pkgs.xorg.libxcb
pkgs.xorg.xcbutilwm
pkgs.xorg.xcbutilimage
pkgs.xorg.xcbutilkeysyms
pkgs.xorg.xcbutilrenderutil
pkgs.xcb-util-cursor

